# How to provide mongoSQLd Authentication failed ERROR 1043 (08S01)

Tags: mongodb

To run BI on project we have used mongsqld to convert the JSON into tables.

On our first installation, everything was running fine and we were able to make analytics.

After installing the security on mongod, the monsqld failes to establish the connection with following error:

`connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:44530 #11219 (1 connection now open)`
`handshake error: ERROR 1043 (08S01): MongoDB schema not yet available`
`end connection 127.0.0.1:44530 (0 connections now open)`

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I had this problem but all I had to do was wait 30 seconds or so for the mongosqld server to generate the schema.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be the case that you haven't set up your mongosqld.conf correctly on your mongo bi connector side.

This will be evident if you check the log files for your mongosqld.conf and find that it has repeated entries for "[Sampler] sampling mongodb for schema permanently". In my case this happened all night until I fixed the config file.

In my particular case - I didnt configure authentication as per the following.

```
  logAppend: false
  path: "/var/log/mongosqld/mongosqld.log"
  verbosity: 2

security:
  enabled: true

mongodb:
  net:
    uri: "mongo.example.com:27017"
    auth:
      username: "root"
      password: "changeme"

net:
  bindIp: 192.0.2.14
  port: 3307
```

As soon as I made the change, uninstalled mongosqld (sudo mongosqld uninstall), installed momgosqld with the new conf (sudo mongosqld install ), and restarted it - it worked.

More about the configuration here - https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/mongosqld/#std-label-config-format